# Prove c exists for f:[0,1] -> R

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, proof-writing

Suppose that a function $f:[0,1] \to \mathbb R$ is continuous in $[0,1]$. Prove that there is a point $c\in [0,1]$ such that $\int_0^1 x^2 f(x)\,dx = \frac{f(c)}{3}$.

Do I somehow use the mean value theorem or FTC?

Comment: I'm not sure how to implement both.

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right track. We shall employ what is known as the (Second) Mean Value Theorem for Integrals which states:

> Assume that $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$ and that $g$ is integrable and nonnegative on $[a,b]$, then there exists a number $c \in[a,b]$ such that
>
> $$\int_{a}^{b}f(x)g(x)dx =f(c) \int_{a}^{b} g(x) dx.$$

Thus appealing to the theorem we get,

$$\int_{0}^{1} x^2 f(x) dx = f(c) \int_{0}^{1} x^2 dx = f(c) \frac{1}{3}.$$